# SSO with Salesforce and Azure AD - disable single logout

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, logout, azure-active-directory

I've started playing with Salesforce and configuring SSO to work with our sandboxes. So far so good, and logins can happen without issue. However, I'm running into a bit of an issue when a user logs out in Salesforce.

What's happening is that when the user selects Logout within salesforce, they get sent to the Azure AD logout, and they are logged out of their current Azure session. This means that I then have to re-sign back into my Azure account to access any new services that I may open.

Is there a way that I can configure things so the only the Salesforce portion is logged out (allowing me to sign in with a different account), without entirely dropping the Azure session?

Comment: Are you using SAML or OpenID Connect

Comment: SAML, using the pre-configured Salesforce app inside Azure AD. Haven't configured user provisioning yet, but that will be next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Salesforce admin console under Single Sign-On Settings, edit your Azure AD config and uncheck `Single Logout Enabled`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work great. Not sure how I missed that option.